# click button on webview upload file for android

Tags: java, android, button, webview

I want to import upload file on webview when clike button on webview.button can not upload file

```
public class BookFullScreenViewActivity extends Activity {
 private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;  
 private void CreateHTML5WebView() {
 mWebView[i] = new HTML5WebView(this);
        mWebView[i].setInitialScale(1);
        mWebView[i].getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView[i].setWebChromeClient(new MyNewWebChromeClient());
}
```

call webview

```
 class MyNewWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{
     public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
         mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            BookFullScreenViewActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

   }
 }
```

onActivity Result

```
  @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int   resultCode,    Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Intent s;
    if (requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

        if (null == mUploadMessage) return;  
        Uri result = data == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null  
                : data.getData();  
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);  
        mUploadMessage = null;

   }
 }
```

when click button onwebview for uploadfile show error on logcat

```
  02-03 17:56:55.401: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(6456): blockWebkitDraw   
  lockedtrue
  02-03 17:56:55.401: V/webview(6456):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent    -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
  02-03 17:56:56.516: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(6456): blockWebkitDraw
  02-03 17:56:56.516: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(6456): blockWebkitDraw  lockedfalse
  02-03 17:56:56.516: V/webview(6456):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
  02-03 17:56:59.356: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(6456): blockWebkitDraw
  02-03 17:56:59.356: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(6456): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
  02-03 17:56:59.356: V/webview(6456):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
  02-03 17:56:59.656: D/webview(6456): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
```